# Should I specify a relationship in EF Core twice in both configurations or only in one?

Tags: c#, configuration, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, relation

Should I specify a relationship in EF Core twice in both configurations or only in one?

E.g. I have these two models:

```
public class A 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int BId { get; set; }

   public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the configuration:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<A> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(a => new { a.Id, a.BId });

        builder
            .HasIndex(a => new { a.Id, a.BId })
            .IsUnique()
            .IsClustered();

        builder
            .HasOne(a => a.B)
            .WithMany(b => b.As)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.BId)
            .IsRequired(true);
    }
```

Should I now add also the:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<B> builder)
    {
        builder
            .HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder
            .HasIndex(b => b.Id)
            .IsUnique()
            .IsClustered();

        builder
            .HasMany(b => b.As)
            .WithOne(a => a.B)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.BId)
            .IsRequired(true);
    }
```

or was the first configuration enough (and hence the second will have no effect) ?

I really can not find an answer to this question on the internet, so I was hoping someone here would now.

Comment: If your db exists, just scaffold it and see what the output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You should not.

**One configuration is absolutely  enough.**

See the docs in following link (Simple blog sample) :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key

> ```
> public class Blog
> {
>     public int BlogId { get; set; }
>     public string Url { get; set; }
>     
>     // Navigation properties
>     public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
>
> }
>     
> public class Post
> {
>      public int PostId { get; set; }
>      public string Title { get; set; }
>      public string Content { get; set; }
>
>      // Navigation properties
>      public Blog Blog { get; set; }
>  }
>
> public class MyContext : DbContext
> {
>       public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
>       public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
>     
>       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>      {
>           modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
>                       .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
>                       .WithMany(b => b.Posts);
>         }
>     }
> ```

If you are not interested in to configuring explicitly, EfCore has 4 Conventions (no configuration needed) for one to many relationships.
Following link explains completely :

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-many-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx